# Is it possible to "de-pipe" the while loop to avoid using the sub-shell process?

Tags: linux, bash, loops, shell

Due to sub-processing on the pipe command, I cannot call out a break to the nested loop, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do 
$(( ( RANDOM % 10 )  + 1 )) | while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
    if [[ $line =~ "10" ]] 
    then
    kill -9 $(pidof RANDOM)
    break
    fi
   done
done
```

Is there a way to rework this? I just want to kill the command process when the matched output is in place and then no longer repeat the loop.

Note: Sorry for the lame example, mostly on killing the process with the PID but it's just to show you what I want to achieve.

Comment: Using `break` in the `while read` loop *should* end the loop (even if it's in a pipeline and therefore a subshell). The writing process will then get a SIGPIPE signal next time it tries to write to the abandoned pipe, which'll generally cause it to exit. I think I clearer example of what you're trying to do would help (this one doesn't really make sense). See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The first `RANDOM` you mention is a variable which yields on each fetch a randon number. The second `RANDOM` is a process with the literal name _RANDOM_. Are you sure that this makes sense somehow?

Answer (score 0):

As `RANDOM` is a bash variable, not a command name, `$(pidof RANDOM)` does not
make sense. Assuming you want to repeat some task for random times, please try:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    # do something here
    if (( ( RANDOM % 10 ) + 1 == 10 )); then
        break
    fi
done
```

or just:

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( i = 0; i < RANDOM % 10 + 1; i++ )); do
    # do something here
done
```

Please note the former code may repeat the task more than 10 times.